# Спрятать пустое поле ListView Android

Tags: java, xml, listview, android

Создал поля в которые выводятся данные, стер с них дефолтный текст,

и их не видно, но вот поле, у которого **background:drawable/back.xml** не скрывается. Как его спрятать?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как на счет свойства visibility? У View есть 3 состояния видимости:

1. View.VISIBLE - видимый
2. View.INVISIBLE - невидимый, но все еще занимает место
3. View.GONE - невидимый, и не занимает место.

программно выставить можно так:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Ну TextView служит шаблоном, если я его сделаю inVISIBLE, то все элементы тоже будет невидимые.

Comment: на картинке у Вас `ListView`? и лучше покажите верстку данного экрана.

Comment: Так сделайте inVISIBLEтем элементам, которые надо спрятать.    
В чем проблема?